# How to reverse PHP array after each time it loops

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, loops, for-loop

How to do a snake loop in PHP or How to reverse PHP array after each time it loops
I'm not sure what this method or technique is called so I'm just going to call it a snake loop.

Basically what I'm trying to do is loop through an array and then reverse the order of that array the next time it loops around.

I have come up with what seems to be a somewhat simple method of doing so, but I just wasn't sure if this was the correct technique or if there was a better way of doing so.

```
<?php
$rounds = 4;
$teams = array('Team 1', 'Team 2', 'Team 3', 'Team 4') ;

for($round = 1; $round <= $rounds; $round++){
    echo "<h1>Round $round</h1>";

    if ($round % 2 == 0) {
        krsort($teams);
    }else{
        asort($teams);
    }        

    foreach($teams as $team){
        echo "$team<br />";
    }
}

?>
```

Output:

```
Round 1
Team 1
Team 2
Team 3
Team 4

Round 2
Team 4
Team 3
Team 2
Team 1

Round 3
Team 1
Team 2
Team 3
Team 4

Round 4
Team 4
Team 3
Team 2
Team 1
```

Basically you can see that the array sorts `ascending` if the `$round` is an odd number and `descending` if it's an even number.

Comment: `$teams = array_reverse($teams);`

Comment: Yeah I tried that earlier and it didn't seem to work. I think I put it within the wrong port of the loop because that seems to be working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use php's [array_reverse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) function.

```
<?php
$rounds = 4;
$teams = array('Team 1', 'Team 2', 'Team 3', 'Team 4') ;

for($round = 1; $round <= $rounds; $round++){
    echo "<h1>Round $round</h1>";
    echo implode("<br/>", $teams);
    $teams = array_reverse($teams);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think reversing arrays is expensive, I think better will be to calculate the inverted index:

```
array A (6 length) 0,1,2,3,4,5

array B (5 length) 0,1,2,3,4

(len-1)-i
//^ this should calculate the inverted index, examples:

//in the array A, if you are index 3: (6-1)-3 = 2, so 3 turns to 2
//in the array A, if you are index 1: (6-1)-1 = 4, so 1 turns to 4
//in the array B, if you are index 3: (5-1)-3 = 1, so 3 turns to 1
//in the array B, if you are index 1: (5-1)-1 = 3, so 1 turns to 3
```

I don't write PHP, but it should be something like this:

```
teams = array('Team 1', 'Team 2', 'Team 3', 'Team 4');
len = teams.length;
myindex; //initializing the var

for(i=0; i<len; i++){
    echo "<h1>Round "+ (i+1) +"</h1>";
    myindex = i;

    if(i%2 == 0) {
        myindex = ((len-1) - i);
    }

    echo team[myindex];
}
```

Comment: How is the alternating odd/even different than `array_reverse`?

Comment: @bigmike7801 I updated my answer, you still need to alternate odd/even, just in one you use the normal index, and in the other you invert it (calculating positions is far better than recreating any array in inverse order)

Comment: OK, I see what you're saying. Basically just have 2 versions of the array at all times rather than reversing it each time.

Comment: @bigmike7801 yes, but not two versions of the array, just 2 versions of the index (which is a small number easily calculated that will tell what item from the array will be fetched)

Comment: `myindex = ((i - 1) - i);` certainly you meant to write `myindex = ((len - 1) - i);`?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your code to implement array_reverse:

```
<?php
$rounds = 4;
$teams = array('Team 1', 'Team 2', 'Team 3', 'Team 4') ;

for($round = 1; $round <= $rounds; $round++){
  echo "<h1>Round $round</h1>";

  if ($round % 2 == 0) {
    $teams = array_reverse($teams);
  }    
  foreach($teams as $team){
    echo "$team<br />";
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[array_reverse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) is the function that returns the reverse of an array.

If you are trying to have the php array object have reversed content on each cycle, then you would need to set the array variable each time; otherwise, you can simply return the output of array_reverse on each cycle.